# Scrollable tabs in android error

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-tabhost, android-tabs

i written a code to implement a scrollable tabs with widgets but unfortunately i have a problem when i start the application:
the Android studio is pointing to this line :

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

if anyone can help me please.

This is my Activity Code :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent intent;

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        Bundle extras =getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), extras.getString("username").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;


    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), "FOUR");
        adapter.addFrag(new FiveFragment(), "FIVE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the layout xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ِAnd this is the Logcat :

```
3-26 07:01:40.136 5424-5424/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d49b20)
03-26 07:01:40.136 5424-5424/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.subhi.hccc, PID: 5424
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.subhi.hccc/com.subhi.hccc.HomePage}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:197)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
                                                     at com.subhi.hccc.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:32)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-26 07:01:40.160 523-816/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.subhi.hccc/.HomePage
03-26 07:01:40.552 523-816/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1011K, 27% free 8922K/12140K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
03-26 07:01:40.576 523-816/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 392K, 27% free 8902K/12140K, paused 12ms, total 13ms
03-26 07:01:40.576 523-816/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity info.androidhive.materialtabs/.activity.ScrollableTabsActivity
03-26 07:01:40.616 523-538/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 12K, 23% free 9384K/12140K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
03-26 07:01:40.616 523-538/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 10.295MB for 1127532-byte allocation
03-26 07:01:40.636 523-538/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 21% free 10484K/13244K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
03-26 07:01:40.652 523-567/? D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
03-26 07:01:40.900 150-150/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
03-26 07:01:41.076 523-538/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{52934b38 u0 com.subhi.hccc/.HomePage t62 f}
03-26 07:01:41.176 4763-4763/? W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-26 07:01:41.936 523-567/? D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
03-26 07:01:42.072 523-567/? D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
03-26 07:01:43.448 5424-5424/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5424 SIG: 9
03-26 07:01:43.452 523-567/? D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
03-26 07:01:43.452 153-503/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 46802 to 39909
03-26 07:01:43.480 523-753/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.subhi.hccc (pid 5424) has died.
```

Comment: what is the error/warning it is showing when you take your cursor to that place? Or any error log you have then it will be helpful to identify the issue.

Comment: check the updates plesas

Comment: put your style xml file, I think you have not taken proper style in your xml thats why it is giving you error.

Comment: post your style/theme you using for this particular activity@AnasMohtasib

Answer (score 0):

make sure your main theme style on the manifest does not extend one of those DarkActionBar styles.
please make sure its extending from a Theme.AppCompat.Light.**NoActionBar** (for instance). otherwise your adding a toolbar on an app that already has a toolbar.

And will raise that error you're seeing on the logcat.

happy coding :)

UPDATE

This is how it look like on your manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/**AppTheme**">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.**NoActionBar**">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: this is totally wrong idea; it's nothing to do with the dark action bar theme; in fact the app theme must have a dark action bar theme to show a custom toolbar; @Sergio Lima

Comment: Bear in mind that on the above snipet of code he's adding a custom toolbar to an activity. If the theme on the manifest already uses one theme with an Actionbar you'll end up with two actionbars. That's why your'e getting that error. make sure that on declaration of the activity on the manifest you specify the theme as <activity  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"  [..remaining stuff..] >  otherwise it will extend from the application theme which could already have an actionbar